# Making a string array show each value followed by an integer array and its values: JAVA

Tags: java

I would like to know how to print out a string which is "Hello index: " and then on each line print out a value in array2 starting with a value of 1, and then adding 5 onto each index as it goes up by 1...if anyone could help, it would be appreciated. I'm a beginner in java, but I know the basics up to arrays. I learned objects and using objects before I did arrays. My question is how can I get the values from each array to print out. And how would I set up my println to print those values. Thank you so much!

```
public class tuna {
private String[] array1;
private int[] array2;

public tuna(String[] array1, int[] array2){
this.array1 = array1;
this.array2 = array2;
}
int i, k;
public String[] getArray1(){
    return array1;
}
public int[] getArray2(){
    return array2;
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] array1 = new String[10];
    int[] array2 = new int[10];
    array2[0] = 1;
    tuna me = new tuna(array1, array2);


    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++){
        array1[i] = "Hello index: ";
    }

    for(int x = 1; x<array2.length - 1; x++){
                    change(array2);
        array2[x] = array2[x-1]; 
        if(array2[x+1] > array2.length)
            array2[x+1] = array2[x];

    }

            me.getArray1();
            me.getArray2();
```

???System.out.println();..........

Comment: what is change(array2);

Comment: Have you looked online for a Java tutorial on Arrays?

Comment: What you're asking is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you mean but if you want to print out a value from your string array you can do this:

```
public class New {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       //makes array, and 10 is how many slots it will have
       String[] array1 = new String[10];
       //sets slot 1 to "Hello"
       array1[1] = "Hello";
       //prints out slot 1
       System.out.println(array1[1]);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class tuna
{
    private String[] array1;
    private int[] array2;

    public tuna(String[] array1, int[] array2)
    {
        this.array1 = array1;
        this.array2 = array2;
    }

    public String[] getArray1()
    {
        return array1;
    }
    public int[] getArray2()
    {
        return array2;
    }
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String[] array1 = new String[10];
    int[] array2 = new int[10];
    array2[0] = 1;
    tuna me = new tuna(array1, array2);

    for(int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++)
    {
        array1[i] = "Hello index: ";
    }

    for(int i = 1; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        change(array2);
        array2[i] = array2[i-1] + 5;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println (array1[i] + array2[i]);
    }
}
```

note however that you do not need a String array for the same message, i.e. Hello index:

Answer (score 0):

> "My question is how can I get the values from each array to print out.
>   And how would I set up my println to print those values"

To print values in an array:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String[] array1 = ..init array //Your code to initialise the array here

    for(String s : array1) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```